# Defining point of rotation when using setRotation in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

So I am using a setRotation to roate a rubbersheet in a QGIS tool and it works but it seems to be rotating based on a corner point of the rectangle and I want to rotate on centre. How do you define a point of rotation when using setRotation?

The code below shows what I am working with. I tagged my entries wih #    tveinot  and the date with a little description as to why I entered those lines. Note this tool was not originally designed by me I am just trying to add a feature.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#    This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#    the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#    (at your option) any later version.
#
#    copyright            : (C) 2014-2015 by Sandro Mani / Sourcepole AG
#    email                : smani@sourcepole.ch

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QSettings, QPointF, QRectF, QRect, QUrl, pyqtSignal, QLocale
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QDesktopServices, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QDialogButtonBox, QMessageBox, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrintDialog, QPrinter
from qgis.core import QgsRectangle, QgsLayoutManager, QgsPointXY as QgsPoint, Qgis, QgsProject, QgsWkbTypes, QgsLayoutExporter, PROJECT_SCALES, QgsLayoutItemMap, QgsGeometry
from qgis.gui import QgisInterface, QgsMapTool, QgsRubberBand
import os
from .ui.ui_printdialog import Ui_InstantPrintDialog

#    tveinot 20200121 Added QgsGeometry, to end of line from qgis.core import QgsRectangle, QgsLayoutManager, QgsPointXY as QgsPoint, Qgis, QgsProject, QgsWkbTypes, QgsLayoutExporter, PROJECT_SCALES, QgsLayoutItemMap

#    tveinot 20200122 Set the rotation value as a placeholder for user defined variable
rot=-45


class InstantPrintDialog(QDialog):

    hidden = pyqtSignal()
    hidden = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)

    def hideEvent(self, ev):
        self.hidden.emit()

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.hidden.emit()


class InstantPrintTool(QgsMapTool, InstantPrintDialog):

    def __init__(self, iface, populateCompositionFz=None):
        QgsMapTool.__init__(self, iface.mapCanvas())

        self.iface = iface
        projectInstance = QgsProject.instance()
        self.projectLayoutManager = projectInstance.layoutManager()
        self.rubberband = None
        self.oldrubberband = None
        self.pressPos = None
        self.printer = QPrinter()
        self.mapitem = None
        self.populateCompositionFz = populateCompositionFz

        self.dialog = InstantPrintDialog(self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.dialogui = Ui_InstantPrintDialog()
        self.dialogui.setupUi(self.dialog)
        self.dialogui.addScale.setIcon(QIcon(":/images/themes/default/mActionAdd.svg"))
        self.dialogui.deleteScale.setIcon(QIcon(":/images/themes/default/symbologyRemove.svg"))
        self.dialog.hidden.connect(self.__onDialogHidden)
        self.exportButton = self.dialogui.buttonBox.addButton(self.tr("Export"), QDialogButtonBox.ActionRole)
        self.printButton = self.dialogui.buttonBox.addButton(self.tr("Print"), QDialogButtonBox.ActionRole)
        self.helpButton = self.dialogui.buttonBox.addButton(self.tr("Help"), QDialogButtonBox.HelpRole)
        self.dialogui.comboBox_fileformat.addItem("PDF", self.tr("PDF Document (*.pdf);;"))
        self.dialogui.comboBox_fileformat.addItem("JPG", self.tr("JPG Image (*.jpg);;"))
        self.dialogui.comboBox_fileformat.addItem("BMP", self.tr("BMP Image (*.bmp);;"))
        self.dialogui.comboBox_fileformat.addItem("PNG", self.tr("PNG Image (*.png);;"))
        self.iface.layoutDesignerOpened.connect(lambda view: self.__reloadLayouts())
        self.iface.layoutDesignerWillBeClosed.connect(self.__reloadLayouts)
        self.dialogui.comboBox_layouts.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.__selectLayout)
        self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.lineEdit().textChanged.connect(self.__changeScale)
        self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.scaleChanged.connect(self.__changeScale)
        self.exportButton.clicked.connect(self.__export)
        self.printButton.clicked.connect(self.__print)
        self.helpButton.clicked.connect(self.__help)
        #    tveinot 20200122 Add spin box entry for changing the rotation value variable (to replace rot)
        self.dialogui.spinbox_Rotation.valueChanged.connect(self.changeRotation)
        self.dialogui.buttonBox.button(QDialogButtonBox.Close).clicked.connect(lambda: self.dialog.hide())
        self.dialogui.addScale.clicked.connect(self.add_new_scale)
        self.dialogui.deleteScale.clicked.connect(self.remove_scale)
        self.deactivated.connect(self.__cleanup)
        self.setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)

        settings = QSettings()
        if settings.value("instantprint/geometry") is not None:
            self.dialog.restoreGeometry(settings.value("instantprint/geometry"))
        if settings.value("instantprint/scales") is not None:
            for scale in settings.value("instantprint/scales").split(";"):
                if scale:
                    self.retrieve_scales(scale)
        self.check_scales()

    #    tveinot 20200122 add def changeRotion... I think this is suppose to grab the new value from the spinbox when it is changed. Still fuzzy on the "def" entries
    def changeRotation(self, newValue):
        self.value=newValue

    def __onDialogHidden(self):
        self.setEnabled(False)
        self.iface.mapCanvas().unsetMapTool(self)
        QSettings().setValue("instantprint/geometry", self.dialog.saveGeometry())
        list = []
        for i in range(self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.count()):
            list.append(self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.itemText(i))
        QSettings().setValue("instantprint/scales", ";".join(list))

    def retrieve_scales(self, checkScale):
        if self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.findText(checkScale) == -1:
            self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.addItem(checkScale)

    def add_new_scale(self):
        new_layout = self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.currentText()
        if self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.findText(new_layout) == -1:
            self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.addItem(new_layout)
        self.check_scales()

    def remove_scale(self):
        layout_to_delete = self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.currentIndex()
        self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.removeItem(layout_to_delete)
        self.check_scales()

    def setEnabled(self, enabled):
        if enabled:
            self.dialog.setVisible(True)
            self.__reloadLayouts()
            self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(self)
        else:
            self.dialog.setVisible(False)
            self.iface.mapCanvas().unsetMapTool(self)

    def __changeScale(self):
        if not self.mapitem:
            return
        newscale = self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.scale()
        if abs(newscale) < 1E-6:
            return
        extent = self.mapitem.extent()
        center = extent.center()
        newwidth = extent.width() / self.mapitem.scale() * newscale
        newheight = extent.height() / self.mapitem.scale() * newscale
        x1 = center.x() - 0.5 * newwidth
        y1 = center.y() - 0.5 * newheight
        x2 = center.x() + 0.5 * newwidth
        y2 = center.y() + 0.5 * newheight
        self.mapitem.setExtent(QgsRectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2))
        self.__createRubberBand()
        self.check_scales()

    def __selectLayout(self):
        if not self.dialog.isVisible():
            return
        activeIndex = self.dialogui.comboBox_layouts.currentIndex()
        if activeIndex < 0:
            return

        layoutView = self.dialogui.comboBox_layouts.itemData(activeIndex)
        maps = []
        layout_name = self.dialogui.comboBox_layouts.currentText()
        layout = self.projectLayoutManager.layoutByName(layout_name)
        for item in layoutView.items():
            if isinstance(item, QgsLayoutItemMap):
                maps.append(item)
        if len(maps) != 1:
            QMessageBox.warning(self.iface.mainWindow(), self.tr("Invalid layout"), self.tr("The layout must have exactly one map item."))
            self.exportButton.setEnabled(False)
            self.iface.mapCanvas().scene().removeItem(self.rubberband)
            self.rubberband = None
            self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.setEnabled(False)
            return

        self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.setEnabled(True)
        self.exportButton.setEnabled(True)

        self.layoutView = layoutView
        self.mapitem = layout.referenceMap()
        self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.setScale(self.mapitem.scale())
        self.__createRubberBand()
        #    tveinot 20200122 set the rubberband rotation
        self.rubberband.setRotation(rot)

    def __createRubberBand(self):
        self.__cleanup()
        extent = self.mapitem.extent()
        center = self.iface.mapCanvas().extent().center()
        self.corner = QPointF(center.x() - 0.5 * extent.width(), center.y() - 0.5 * extent.height())
        self.rect = QRectF(self.corner.x(), self.corner.y(), extent.width(), extent.height())
        self.mapitem.setExtent(QgsRectangle(self.rect))
        self.rubberband = QgsRubberBand(self.iface.mapCanvas(), QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry)
        self.rubberband.setToCanvasRectangle(self.__canvasRect(self.rect))
        #    tveinot 20200122 set the rubberband rotation
        self.rubberband.setRotation(rot)
        self.rubberband.setColor(QColor(127, 127, 255, 127))

        self.pressPos = None

    def __cleanup(self):
        if self.rubberband:
            self.iface.mapCanvas().scene().removeItem(self.rubberband)
        if self.oldrubberband:
            self.iface.mapCanvas().scene().removeItem(self.oldrubberband)
        self.rubberband = None
        self.oldrubberband = None
        self.pressPos = None

    def canvasPressEvent(self, e):
        if not self.rubberband:
            return
        r = self.__canvasRect(self.rect)
        if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.__canvasRect(self.rect).contains(e.pos()):
            self.oldrect = QRectF(self.rect)
            self.oldrubberband = QgsRubberBand(self.iface.mapCanvas(), QgsWkbTypes.PolygonGeometry)
            self.oldrubberband.setToCanvasRectangle(self.__canvasRect(self.oldrect))
            #    tveinot 20200122 set the rubberband rotation
            self.rubberband.setRotation(rot)
            self.oldrubberband.setColor(QColor(127, 127, 255, 31))
            self.pressPos = (e.x(), e.y())
            self.iface.mapCanvas().setCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)

    def canvasMoveEvent(self, e):
        if not self.pressPos:
            return
        mup = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().mapUnitsPerPixel()
        x = self.corner.x() + (e.x() - self.pressPos[0]) * mup
        y = self.corner.y() + (self.pressPos[1] - e.y()) * mup

        snaptol = 10 * mup
        # Left edge matches with old right
        if abs(x - (self.oldrect.x() + self.oldrect.width())) < snaptol:
            x = self.oldrect.x() + self.oldrect.width()
        # Right edge matches with old left
        elif abs(x + self.rect.width() - self.oldrect.x()) < snaptol:
            x = self.oldrect.x() - self.rect.width()
        # Left edge matches with old left
        elif abs(x - self.oldrect.x()) < snaptol:
            x = self.oldrect.x()
        # Bottom edge matches with old top
        if abs(y - (self.oldrect.y() + self.oldrect.height())) < snaptol:
            y = self.oldrect.y() + self.oldrect.height()
        # Top edge matches with old bottom
        elif abs(y + self.rect.height() - self.oldrect.y()) < snaptol:
            y = self.oldrect.y() - self.rect.height()
        # Bottom edge matches with old bottom
        elif abs(y - self.oldrect.y()) < snaptol:
            y = self.oldrect.y()

        self.rect = QRectF(
            x,
            y,
            self.rect.width(),
            self.rect.height()
        )
        self.rubberband.setToCanvasRectangle(self.__canvasRect(self.rect))
        #    tveinot 20200122 set the rubberband rotation
        self.rubberband.setRotation(rot)

    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, e):
        if e.button() == Qt.LeftButton and self.pressPos:
            self.corner = QPointF(self.rect.x(), self.rect.y())
            self.pressPos = None
            self.iface.mapCanvas().setCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)
            self.iface.mapCanvas().scene().removeItem(self.oldrubberband)
            self.oldrect = None
            self.oldrubberband = None
            self.mapitem.setExtent(QgsRectangle(self.rect))

    def __canvasRect(self, rect):
        mtp = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapSettings().mapToPixel()
        p1 = mtp.transform(QgsPoint(rect.left(), rect.top()))
        p2 = mtp.transform(QgsPoint(rect.right(), rect.bottom()))
        return QRect(p1.x(), p1.y(), p2.x() - p1.x(), p2.y() - p1.y())

    def __export(self):
        settings = QSettings()
        format = self.dialogui.comboBox_fileformat.itemData(self.dialogui.comboBox_fileformat.currentIndex())
        filepath = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            self.iface.mainWindow(),
            self.tr("Export Layout"),
            settings.value("/instantprint/lastfile", ""),
            format
        )
        if not all(filepath):
            return

        # Ensure output filename has correct extension
        filename = os.path.splitext(filepath[0])[0] + "." + self.dialogui.comboBox_fileformat.currentText().lower()
        settings.setValue("/instantprint/lastfile", filepath[0])

        if self.populateCompositionFz:
            self.populateCompositionFz(self.layoutView.composition())

        success = False
        layout_name = self.dialogui.comboBox_layouts.currentText()
        layout_item = self.projectLayoutManager.layoutByName(layout_name)
        exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout_item)
        if filename[-3:].lower() == u"pdf":
            success = exporter.exportToPdf(filepath[0], QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
        else:
            success = exporter.exportToImage(filepath[0], QgsLayoutExporter.ImageExportSettings())
        if success != 0:
            QMessageBox.warning(self.iface.mainWindow(), self.tr("Export Failed"), self.tr("Failed to export the layout."))

    def __print(self):
        layout_name = self.dialogui.comboBox_layouts.currentText()
        layout_item = self.projectLayoutManager.layoutByName(layout_name)
        actual_printer = QgsLayoutExporter(layout_item)

        printdialog = QPrintDialog(self.printer)
        if printdialog.exec_() != QDialog.Accepted:
            return

        success = actual_printer.print(self.printer, QgsLayoutExporter.PrintExportSettings())

        if success != 0:
            QMessageBox.warning(self.iface.mainWindow(), self.tr("Print Failed"), self.tr("Failed to print the layout."))

    def __reloadLayouts(self, removed=None):
        if not self.dialog.isVisible():
            # Make it less likely to hit the issue outlined in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/1938
            return

        self.dialogui.comboBox_layouts.blockSignals(True)
        prev = None
        if self.dialogui.comboBox_layouts.currentIndex() >= 0:
            prev = self.dialogui.comboBox_layouts.currentText()
        self.dialogui.comboBox_layouts.clear()
        active = 0
        for layout in self.projectLayoutManager.layouts():
            if layout != removed and layout.name():
                cur = layout.name()
                self.dialogui.comboBox_layouts.addItem(cur, layout)
                if prev == cur:
                    active = self.dialogui.comboBox_layouts.count() - 1
        self.dialogui.comboBox_layouts.setCurrentIndex(-1)  # Ensure setCurrentIndex below actually changes an index
        self.dialogui.comboBox_layouts.blockSignals(False)
        if self.dialogui.comboBox_layouts.count() > 0:
            self.dialogui.comboBox_layouts.setCurrentIndex(active)
            self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.setEnabled(True)
            self.exportButton.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.exportButton.setEnabled(False)
            self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.setEnabled(False)

    def __help(self):
        manualPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "help", "documentation.pdf")
        QDesktopServices.openUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile(manualPath))

    def scaleFromString(self, scaleText):
        locale = QLocale()
        parts = [locale.toInt(part) for part in scaleText.split(":")]
        try:
            if len(parts) == 2 and parts[0][1] and parts[1][1] and parts[0][0] != 0 and parts[1][0] != 0:
                return float(parts[0][0]) / float(parts[1][0])
            else:
                return None
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return

    def check_scales(self):
        predefScalesStr = QSettings().value("Map/scales", PROJECT_SCALES).split(",")
        predefScales = [self.scaleFromString(scaleString) for scaleString in predefScalesStr]

        comboScalesStr = [self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.itemText(i) for i in range(self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.count())]
        comboScales = [self.scaleFromString(scaleString) for scaleString in comboScalesStr]

        currentScale = self.scaleFromString(self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.currentText())

        if not currentScale:
            self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.lineEdit().setStyleSheet("background: #FF7777; color: #FFFFFF;")
            self.dialogui.addScale.setVisible(True)
            self.dialogui.addScale.setEnabled(False)
            self.dialogui.deleteScale.setVisible(False)
        else:
            self.dialogui.comboBox_scale.lineEdit().setStyleSheet("")
            if currentScale in comboScales:
                # If entry scale is already in the list, allow removing it unless it is a predefined scale
                self.dialogui.addScale.setVisible(False)
                self.dialogui.deleteScale.setVisible(True)
                self.dialogui.deleteScale.setEnabled(currentScale not in predefScales)
            else:
                # Otherwise, show button to add it
                self.dialogui.addScale.setVisible(True)
                self.dialogui.addScale.setEnabled(True)
                self.dialogui.deleteScale.setVisible(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case I found that I can use setTransformOriginPoint before my setRotation line to specify the point of rotation.

```
        self.rubberband.setTransformOriginPoint((self.rect.width()),(self.rect.height()))
    self.rubberband.setRotation(mapRotation)
```

I thought it should be half hight, width bit that spun it off centre (code below)

```
        self.rubberband.setTransformOriginPoint((0.5 * self.rect.width()), (0.5 * 
self.rect.height()))
        self.rubberband.setRotation(map_rotation)
```

My first attempt I was using

```
self.rubberband.setTransformOriginPoint((center.x(), (center.y())
```

It seemed like this wasn't working, but it was it is just that using setTransformOriginPoint on a rubberband rectangle it is looking for values that reference the point of origin of the rectangle. So those X, Y, coordinates were being projected from the lower left corrner of the rectangle. Changing it to reference the half the length, width, from the origin point placed the point of rotation in the center of the rectangle.
Now all I need to do is figure out how to get the "rot" value to equal the value in my spinbox and pass that to the Map Rotation value in the specified layout.

Comment: Ok, something is off. The point of rotation changes depending on the scale of my map view. The further out I am zoomed the further East the point of rotation is. I am trying to set the rotation to the midpoint of the rectangle reguardless of it's position on the map.